# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have written a Spark Job in Java. When I submit the Job it gives below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.veon.util.SparkSessionBuilder.getOrCreateSparkSession(SparkSessionBuilder.java:12)
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.veon.AbstractSparkTransformation.initSparkSession(AbstractSparkTransformation.java:92)
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.veon.transformations.SDPServiceFeeDeductionSourceToEventStore.init(SDPServiceFeeDeductionSourceToEventStore.java:57)
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.veon.AbstractSparkTransformation.doTransform(AbstractSparkTransformation.java:51)
        at com.thinkbiganalytics.veon.transformations.SDPServiceFeeDeductionSourceToEventStore.main(SDPServiceFeeDeductionSourceToEventStore.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:745)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide your `pom.xml` file if you use **Maven* or the `build.gradle` file if you work with **Gradle**. This would make this question way more helpful for other users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when submitting  with `spark-submit` , check that your project has the same dependency as spark version in pom.xml,

**This may be because you have two spark versions on the same machine**

---

If you want to have different Spark installations on your machine,  you can create different soft links and can use the exact spark version on which you have build your project

```
spark1-submit -> /Users/test/sparks/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit

spark2–submit -> /Users/test/sparks/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit
```

Here is a link from Cloudera blog about multiple Spark versions
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Multiple-Spark-version-on-the-same-cluster/td-p/39880

Answer (score 34):

If you're running from inside Intellij IDEA, and you've marked your spark library as "provided", like so: `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.1" % "provided"`, Then you need edit your Run/Debug configuration and check the "Include dependencies with Provided scope" box.

Answer (score 21):

I was facing this issue while running from the Intellij editor. I had marked the spark jars as provided in `pom.xml`, see below:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

On removing the provided scope, the error was gone.

On making provided spark jars they would be provided only on running the application with `spark-submit` or having the spark jars on the classpath

Comment: Worked! I had copy pasted this from sparkml examples, that's where the scope variable crept it for me. Thanks.

Comment: Don't remove it. You should follow this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66510343/2308683

Answer (score 12):

If you are running from IntelliJ, please check for "Include dependencies with Provided scope" as follows

Inside Run/Debug Configuration please select for Modify Options and then mark checked "Include dependencies with Provided scope"

[image: Inside Run/Debug Configuration please select for Modify Options and then check]

Answer (score 7):

Probably you are deploying your application on the cluster with lower Spark version.

Please check Spark version on your cluster - it should be the same as version in pom.xml. Please also note, that all Spark dependencies should be marked as `provided` when you use spark-submit to deploy application

Comment: In which file I need to mark the spark dependencies as provided?

Comment: In Maven pom.xml

Comment: I faced exactly the same issue when running spark 2.1 program with spark 1.6. I solved my issue by stopping 1.6 cluster and starting 2.1 cluster and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If using Maven, go to your dependencies file(`pom.xml`) and change the scope from `provided` to `compile`.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.0</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try to avoid this fix. The provided value shouldn't be changed. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66510343/13867124) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 2):

Go to edit configuration and modify the configuration as per my screenshot:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99qQ3.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

As per the exception you are getting ,I think required jar is missing you need to add the required jar in your classpath which will resolve the issue.

refer this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10) to download the required jar

Comment: I think there is no Jar related Issue. Because I have executed couple of spark jobs on same environment before in past and they ran successfully.

Comment: @Umar did you use SparkSession in those jobs or SparkContext? Which version of spark are you using? You need to add more information about your environment and how are you creating and executing the jar.

Comment: Yes.. In my previous jobs I had Spark Session and Context. I am using Spark version 2.1.1 and building the Jar file using Maven.

Answer (score 0):

leaking of jars of spark environment will lead to this problem 
if you were using Intellij IDEA,you can following the steps below:
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> spark-examples_2.11 -> Dependencies 
jars -> {spark dir}/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars/

Answer (score 0):

I am using Maven project, got the same issue, I changed "provided" to "compile" in scope, pom.xml dependencies and made the same spark version which was installed in local spark shell. Problem got resolved.

Comment: Try to avoid this fix. The `provided` value shouldn't be changed. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66510343/13867124) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case downgrading the `Java version` from `Java 18` to `Java 8` fixed this issue. If someone knows why exactly the downgrade fixed the issue please comment and explain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Intellij`, and had added a dependency in `build.sbt` do it like this:

```
[libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.4.1" % "provided" ]
```

If what I provided is mentioned then right click on the main file (scala object, scala class or Java) and click `run <file name>`, this will run the file and create a configuration. And in the configuration you can modify it and choose: add dependency with provided scope.